# Issue deserializing array of int from JSON post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I am seeing really odd behavior when trying to submit a JSON payload via Ajax post to my MVC controller.

Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ResetEligibility(EmployeeEligibilityFilter filter) { ... }

public class EmployeeEligibilityFilter
{
    public List<int> Selection { get; set; }
    public bool SelectionInverted { get; set; }
    public int? BenACACalendarCycleId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Payload that works:

```
{"BenACACalendarCycleId":2,"SelectionInverted":false,"Selection":[680,698,875]}
```

Now if I supply `Selection` list with less than 3 elements, the `Selection` property suddenly starts coming up as `null` on the server side.

```
{"BenACACalendarCycleId":2,"SelectionInverted":false,"Selection":[680,875]}
```

Other properties continue deserialize correctly.

We're lost and confused here...

---

**More investigation**: Changing model property from `List<int>` to `List<object>` magically makes things work. The elements stored in the object list are still `System.Int32` though.
I even tried to use both side by side like this:

```
public class EmployeeEligibilityFilter
{
    public int? BenACACalendarCycleId { get; set; }
    public bool SelectionInverted { get; set; }
    public List<int> Selection { get; set; }
    public List<object> _Selection { get; set; }
}
```

and send the exact same array in both:

```
{"BenACACalendarCycleId":2,"SelectionInverted":false,"Selection":[663],"_Selection":[663]}
```

The end result is still the same. `Selection` comes up as null, but `_Selection` is deserialized correctly.

Voodoo magic...

Comment: Could you run fiddler and post the result of the two different queries you posted here?

Comment: I would like to see a snippet of the code used to do the post, some of the code inside of ResetEligibility, and the results of a little bit of spying with a tool like Fiddler, before taking the time to whip out a test app. (Looks like James suggested the same.)

Comment: The two JSON payloads that I posted are taken from Fiddler, i.e. this is exactly what is being sent to the server. `ResetEligibility` action doesn't actually do anything yet. I see the breakage by setting a breakpoint inside the method and inspecting `filter` parameter

Comment: I think may the deserializer is seeing the comma as a decimal separator, try to change the List to List<decimal> as a little test...

Comment: It seems to be working with `decimal`, but I doubt comma is the issue here. In my last iteration i was testing with a single selection value, which wouldn't have a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void GetAAA() {

            var json = "{'BenACACalendarCycleId':2,'SelectionInverted':false,'Selection':[663],'_Selection':[663]}";

            EmployeeEligibilityFilter obj = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<EmployeeEligibilityFilter>(json); 

        }

        public class EmployeeEligibilityFilter
        {
            public int? BenACACalendarCycleId { get; set; }
            public bool SelectionInverted { get; set; }
            public List<int> Selection { get; set; }
            public List<object> _Selection { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: This works correctly. A logical conclusion would be that there is some kind of filter or custom binder that screws up the action parameter, but we don't have anything like that...